# Old science fiction movie where main characters are launched into a star or some sort of anomaly and die

Tags: story-identification, movie, spaceship, robots

A couple years ago, I watched an old movie (Made a little before or a little after Star Wars) about these people who were in this large ship, and I remember that there was only other one human on it, directing an army of physically altered human slaves. There was something about that human being one of the main characters’ parent’s friend, or something like that. The slaves turned on the main characters. I remember specifically a scene where one of the main characters is thrown into a hole that electrocutes and kills them. Also, at the end, there was something about the main characters being launched from the ship into a star or something.

Comment: Disney's '*The Black Hole*'? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Black_Hole_(1979_film)

Comment: Classy: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HyULTU9smVQ

Comment: Yep, that’s it! When I first watched it, I thought that the plot was a little weird.

Comment: Supposedly, it was supposed to be even weirder, with it being explicit that traveling through the black hole took you through heaven and hell. I marked this question as a duplicate, but that's no censure on you, just a matter of bookkeeping.

Comment: Yeah. That scene confused me, and it looked really weird. I thought somehow it had teleported to some sort of fireball.

Comment: I wonder whether Lucas got inspired by V.I.N.CENT's EVA scene for the R2D2 EVA scene in "Phantom Menace".